# Contact form 7 remove default validation for radio button

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I want to prevent default required validation for radio button in contact form 7 WordPress.

check below image this both field is not mandatory still its give me ("This field required message and prevent the form from submitting")

[image]

Comment: What about a little trick like adding separate radio to the form with the same name like your existing radio, wrap it into invisible container and add the only choice like "Not Selected" ? I havent tried, but think it should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way using radio button but we can achieve the same thing using contact form checkbox exclusive property

**[checkbox your-country exclusive "China" "India" "San Marino"]**

**And Using CSS I made checkbox look like as radio button.**

[click here](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

There is no required version of radio. The reason Contact Form 7 doesn’t provide “radio*” is because a radio button is a required field by nature.

At all times, exactly one of the radio buttons in a set is checked. If none of the  elements of a set of radio buttons specifies `CHECKED', then the user agent must check the first radio button of the set initially.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio explains it more in detail.

Comment: what if I want to make this field not required. is there anyway?